# How to set the height of child div element from its position to the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css

The code below is `panel.css` and `panel.html`. I am trying to set the height of `div.sidebar` and `div.content` from its position to the bottom of the page. But setting their height to 100% doesn't actually set their height to the bottom of the page. Instead their height are short. How can I set their height to the bottom of the page?

panel.css

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
}
 #header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #120103;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
 #header div{
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  float: left;
 }
 #header div a{
  font-size: 1.6em;
  color: #fff;

 }
 #header div a span{
  color: #ebebeb;
 }

 .container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }

 .sidebar{
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #171717;
  float: left;
 }

 ul li{
  list-style: none;
 }

 a {text-decoration: none;}

 ul li a{
  display: block;
  padding:10px;
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 0.8em;

 }

 .content{
  background: lightblue;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 250px;
  padding:15px;
 }

 div.box{
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin-left:10px; 
 }
 div.box div.box-top{
  color:#fff;
  background: #120103;
  
 }

 div.box div.box-panel{
  color:#333;
  background:#fff;
  border: 1px solid rgb(44, 47, 40);
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Panel</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src ="panel.css">
<body>
 <div id="header">
  <div>
   <a>
   This is <span>header</span>
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sidebar 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sidebar 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sidebar 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sidebar 4</a></li>

   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   <div class="box">
    <div class="box-top">What's new?</div>
     <div class="box-panel">
      Lalalalala!
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    <div class="box-top">What's new?</div>
     <div class="box-panel">
      Lorem Ipsum what some want some super some greate some! 
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    <div class="box-top">What's new?</div>
     <div class="box-panel">
      Lalalalala!
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always a good habit to set the height of html and body to 100% to make sure any child elements are sized properly.  The same goes for all parent elements.  100% sizes to the parent, and if the parent's height is zero, the contents will still show because it's overflowing, but 100% of zero is still zero. ;)

Personally, I'm a fan of using `html, body { min-height: 100vh; }` so the page is never smaller than the window.

If you know the element's vertical position, you can use calc to help you size an element from its current position down to the bottom of the parent.  Say for example, your element starts at 250px, and your page is 2000px tall.

CSS

```
.page { height: 2000px; }
.topElement { height: 250px; }
.bottomElement { height: calc(100% - 250px) }
```

HTML

```
<body class="page">
  <div class="topElement"></div>
  <div class="bottomElement"></div>
</div>
```

That, or you could use css grid to lay out your pages, which is really handy, but may provide some compatibility concerns.

```
.page {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 250px auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jon DeWitt. This information was really helpful. I was about to give up on CSS.

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

Add 100% height on html and body

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
} 
   html, body {
  height: 100%;
   }
 #header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #120103;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
 #header div{
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  float: left;
 }
 #header div a{
  font-size: 1.6em;
  color: #fff;

 }
 #header div a span{
  color: #ebebeb;
 }

 .container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }

 .sidebar{
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #171717;
  float: left;
 }

 ul li{
  list-style: none;
 }

 a {text-decoration: none;}

 ul li a{
  display: block;
  padding:10px;
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 0.8em;

 }

 .content{
  background: lightblue;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 250px;
 }

 div.box{
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin-left:10px; 
 }
 div.box div.box-top{
  color:#fff;
  background: #120103;
  
 }

 div.box div.box-panel{
  color:#333;
  background:#fff;
  border: 1px solid rgb(44, 47, 40);
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Panel</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src ="panel.css">
<body>
 <div id="header">
  <div>
   <a>
   This is <span>header</span>
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sidebar 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sidebar 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sidebar 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sidebar 4</a></li>

   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   <div class="box">
    <div class="box-top">What's new?</div>
     <div class="box-panel">
      Lalalalala!
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    <div class="box-top">What's new?</div>
     <div class="box-panel">
      Lorem Ipsum what some want some super some greate some! 
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    <div class="box-top">What's new?</div>
     <div class="box-panel">
      Lalalalala!
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```